# sharepoint 2007: how to open pdf in adobe reader?

Tags: sharepoint, pdf

when opening PDF file from sharepoint file it opens as web view and not using Adobe Reader (which installed on the client).

Can some one suggest how to make it open in Adobe reader?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a client setting, not something you have control over from the web. Even if it were possible, with a workaround/hack to change the behaviour, it would be bad practice to do so, since the user may have picked in their preferences to have PDFs display in browser.

You can point them at an article like this: http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-pdf-from-opening-in-web-browser-ie-firefox-opera-safari/ to help them let all their PDFs open in a new Adobe Reader session.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple browser add-on setting. Adobe has posted instructions for multiple browsers at:

[Display PDF in Browser](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html)